# Can't plot polygons with R: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4?

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, error, ggplot2

I want to plot a map of my region, with colour filled polygons using R. I have downloaded municipal (lines) and province (polygons) boundaries. I've used SAGA to merge municipal and province shapes to produce new boundaries (polygons) to read and plot with R and ggplot2.

I succesfully plotted the original province (polygons) but failed to plot new boundaries (polygons) with this error message:

> Error en createPolygonsComment(p) :    IllegalArgumentException:
>   Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4

Maybe I made some mistake when merging original polygons and lines to create the new boundaries. Shoud I check shp attributes?

You can find original boundaries [here](http://ubuntuone.com/7VMshSPgseaeJm2B7SXOz3) and newly created ones [here](http://ubuntuone.com/2gUfjDFLGdkKmXim02KFtm)

**EDIT:** Added link to data file [lineas_limites_municipales_etrs89.dbf](http://ubuntuone.com/5V7dvqNhoCnKDIn3DTFrfy)

And the original R code I used to plot original boundaries, not working for new ones (see error message above):

```
require("rgdal")
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")

# Reading municipal boundaries

 esp = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="lineas_limite_municipales_etrs89")

 muni=subset(esp, esp$PROV1 == "46" | esp$PROV1 == "12" | esp$PROV1 == "3")
 muni@data$id = rownames(muni@data)
 muni.points = fortify(muni,region="id")
 muni.df = join(muni.points, muni@data, by="id")

# Reading province boundaries

prov = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="poligonos_provincia_etrs89")

pr=subset(prov, prov$CODINE == "46" | prov$CODINE == "12" | prov$CODINE == "03" )
pr@data$id = rownames(pr@data)
pr.points = fortify(pr, region="id")
pr.df = join(pr.points, pr@data, by="id")

ggplot(muni.df) + aes(long,lat,group=group) + geom_path(color="blue") +
coord_equal()+ geom_path(data=pr.df,   aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),color="red", size=0.5)
```

Comment: There is a problem in boundaries.tar: `lineas_limite_municipales_etrs89.dbf.gz` is not a gzip file (it seems to be overwritten by a tar file which contain .prj, .shp, .shx files)

Comment: Hi @rcs Newly created tar data uploaded, hope it works now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: doesn't work, `lineas_limite_municipales_etrs89.dbf.gz` is still a tar archive (in boundaries.tar) ... see here: http://pastebin.com/WZr9UfKg

Comment: @rcs Thanks for your patience. Added link just to the dbf file. I've extracted again from original downloaded zip file.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me with the data you provide. Generally, your error does point to a problem with the GEOS library not being able to deal with the geometry, but I cannot reproduce it. I have rgeos version 0.2-16 and GEOS runtime version: 3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4.

Comment: Hi @cengel I'm running R 3.0 with rgdal version 0.8-9, GDAL 1.7.3 and rgeos version: 0.3-1, GEOS runtime version: 3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2 (not yours). As there are updates for both rgeos and rgdal I'm gonna try.

Comment: After updating rgeos and rgdal, GEOS runtime version still not updated, the problem persists. Should try to update to GEOS 3.3.3? How to do it? can't find it in synaptic (Ubuntu 12.04) Maybe I need to add another repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling that there is at least one corrupt polygon among your data, i.e., a polygon with more than 0 and less than 4 points (0 < points < 4). See [Tidying feature geometries with sf](http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/03/19/invalid.html#corrup-or-invalid-geometries) for instructions on how to inspect and fix the data, if it is the case.

**However**, I could not download "original boundaries" (it seems the link is broken), but this is what I got (I think the same as @cengel) with data provided on second link (+ the .dbf file link):

```
require(rgdal)
require(maptools)
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)

# Reading municipal boundaries

esp = readOGR(dsn="C:\\...\\boundaries", layer="lineas_limite_municipales_etrs89")

muni=subset(esp, esp$PROV1 == "46" | esp$PROV1 == "12" | esp$PROV1 == "3")
muni@data$id = rownames(muni@data)
muni.points = fortify(muni,region="id")
muni.df = join(muni.points, muni@data, by="id")

#Adapted ggplot function to existing data
ggplot(muni.df) + aes(long,lat,group=group) + geom_path(color="blue") +
coord_equal() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @andre-silva I have also plotted municipal boundaries but what I wanted was to create polygons by merging municipal lines and province polygons. When I have time I will restart creating the polygons and then post here again the right ones to try to find a solution.